# ADB connection issue on Chromebook

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, chromebook

I'm developing Android app for Chromebook on Mac and debugging through Wi-Fi ADB connection.
But ADB connection will be disconnected after a few minutes.

What should I do to keep stable ADB connection?
I had no problems when I was debugging Android devices (Nexus5, Xperia, etc) through USB connection.

**Environment**
macOS 10.12.4
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
Android Studio 2.3.1
Aser Chromebook R11 (Developer mode)
Wi-Fi network is working well

Comment: Where you able to find any solution to this?

Comment: Update ChromeOS, this problem was solved.